# How can my Nginx Docker container, created through the GitLab CI/CD, use the html-files inside my repository?

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, raspberry-pi4, gitlab-ce

to understand more about this topic I have set up multiple Docker container on my Raspberry Pi4 with the target of creating a functioning workflow.

## Setup

Firstly, I have a working GitLab Community Edition with this [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/ulm0/gitlab/) (due to compatibility for ARM).
Secondly, there is also the [GitLab Runner](https://hub.docker.com/r/klud/gitlab-runner/) I use, which is connected to the GitLab as well.
Lastly, I have created myself a docker-compose file with which an Nginx-Container is being created from this [image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx). The creation of the Nginx-Container without the use of CI/CD works perfectly fine.

## Problem

Now to the problem itself: 
The CI/CD is enabled and the Runner is assigned to the pipeline. Inside the repository is the index.html (in the folder "html"), a .gitlab-ci.yml file and the docker-compose.yml. Here are the contents of the two .yml files:

#### .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: docker:dind

variables:
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"

services:
  - docker:dind

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache docker-compose
    - docker-compose up -d
```

#### docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx: 
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /builds/Dennis/first-project/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
    ports:
      - "20080:80"
      - "20022:22"
      - "20443:443"
    privileged: true
```

The pipeline installs docker-compose and creates the container. I can even access the Nginx-container through the IP and Port, but receive the error message "403 Forbidden". A look into the logs of this container outputs the following error:

```
directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden
```

I took a look inside the directory of this container while running, however there is no content inside "/usr/share/nginx/html/", which led me to believe that the pipeline or docker-compose don't have access to the files inside the repository or the path is configured falsely (most likely the second ). I tried to tinker a bit with the path in the docker-compose.yml (the first part of "volumes"), but to no avail.


In which way do I have to edit my configuration, maybe only my path in docker-compose.yml, so that the creation of the Nginx container takes the files from the repository?

Comment: It sounds like you are starting a container, to then build another nginx container via docker-compose. Your first container (docker:dind) doesn't have the /builds/Dennis/first-project/html folder so your second container (nginx) doesn't bind it. As a test you can try manually copying the files to that folder via 'docker cp' to see if it works.

Comment: I understand your point and tried working with that. The main problem now seems to be a cryptic naming of the created container. This is one of the container names:
`runner-etpyh7rx-project-1-concurrent-0-0901edda5024dce0-build-2`
I tried working with
`services:
  - name: docker:dind
    alias: docker-temp`
as a form of being able to reference the container by its name (or rather alias) for then to use docker cp. However the alias does not seem to be accepted by my runner, even though I used the same syntax as in the documentation for the .gitlab-ci.yml.

Comment: The runner will create arbitrary names for the gitlab jobs based on the runner name (etpyh7rx) and the project/commit details. You should never need to know this name. Another way is to put the files you need in your nginx container in the git repo, then copy them to the container in your docker-compose file.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution! To me it feels like this isn't the best possible fix, but it works nonetheless. Thank you very much.